# Express with FIREBASE I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I'm working in a firebase project, and I'm trying to follow a tutorial and I can find the fix. 
I have seen this type of validation in other projects and it should work, but I don't know what I'm missing in my code.

I getting

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined*

This is for a POST request

```
exports.createContact= (req, res)=>{
    if (req.body.body.trim() === '') {   // ERROR HERE WHEN VALIDATING

    return res.status(400).json({ body: 'Body must not be empty' });
  }
...
}
```

This is the index.js

```
"use strict";
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const {createContact}= require('./handlers/contacts');

//middle ware 

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// server functions

app.post('/contact', createContact);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How does the client of the API make the request? Would you post it in the OP, please?

Comment: Hello @laruiss I'm using POSTMAN to send the post request 
`http://localhost:5000/api/contact`
I put a raw body like in JSON format
{
   "phone": "4444444"
}

Comment: So in `req.body`, you will get an object corresponding to what you sent, so `{phone: '4444444}`, there will be no `req.body.body`, only `req.body.phone`

Comment: Hi @laruiss , I can validate using just req.body,  but my question now is why should I use req.body.body or if its something useful o needed  for firebase in particular?

Comment: Who told you that you had to or that you should use `req.body.body`?

Comment: I'm following  this tutorial  [link](https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-functions/blob/master/functions/handlers/screams.js)
And I also see this type of validation in other examples, it is specific in firebase examples.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in question (req.body.body), You can do like this,

```
if (!(req.body.body || '').trim()) {   // ERROR HERE WHEN VALIDATING
    return res.status(400).json({ body: 'Body must not be empty' });
}
```

But If your request body is like this req.body, You can do like this,

```
if (!req.body || !Object.keys(req.body).length) { 
    return res.status(400).json({ body: 'Body must not be empty' });
}
```

Comment: I used  `(!(req.body.body || '').trim())`
but its always returning 'Body must not be empty', even if I send a body or I leave it empty.

Comment: I can validate using  just `req.body`  but  my question now is why should I use `req.body.body` ?

Comment: Think like you are passing email in body, `req.body.email` mean `req.body` object has property email... Similarly, `req.body.body`  mean your req.body object has a key body. So your request body  is `req.body` not `req.body.body`.